# Returning user profile data using Retrofit Json Parsing

Tags: android, json, retrofit

i'm having a difficulty returning user data from retrofit. I want to return the data from the server and insert into Shared Preferences to maintain a user session
Here is my JsonResponse from the server

```
{
    "result":"success",
    "message":"Your Login was successful...Welcome",
    "bool":"true",
    "user":{
          "firstname":"Steve",
          "lastname":"Karuma",
          "phone":"0728753983",
          "natID":"29775996",
          "emailAddress":"stevekaruma@gmail.com",
          "unique_id":"589496660cd8e1.44744002"
          }
}
```

Here is my login process code snippet

```
private void loginProcess(String phone, String password) {

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Just a moment");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading....");
    progressDialog.show();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();

    RequestInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(RequestInterface.class);

    ShopUser user = new ShopUser();
    user.setPhone(phone);
    user.setPassword(password);
    ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
    request.setOperation(Constants.LOGIN_OPERATION);
    request.setUser(user);

    Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);

    response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, retrofit2.Response<ServerResponse> response) {

            ServerResponse resp = response.body();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),resp.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.i(Constants.TAG,resp.getMessage());

            if(resp.getResult().equals(Constants.SUCCESS)){
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,true);
                editor.putString(Constants.FIRST_NAME, resp.getUser().getFirstname());
                editor.putString(Constants.LAST_NAME, resp.getUser().getLastname());
                editor.putString(Constants.EMAIL, resp.getUser().getEmail());
                editor.putString(Constants.PHONE, resp.getUser().getPhone());
                editor.putString(Constants.ID_NUMBER, resp.getUser().getNatID());
                editor.putString(Constants.UNIQUE_ID, resp.getUser().getUnique_id());
                editor.apply();
                goToProfile();

            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {

            Log.d(Constants.TAG,"Failed");
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),t.getLocalizedMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: What is the error ?

Comment: and where is your question?

Comment: sorry, the question is why isn't my data being returned. Even when i use Log to display the results, nothing is being returned

Comment: post ServerResponse class

Comment: Here is my server response class

Comment: Here is my server response classpublic class ServerResponse {
    private String result;
    private String message;
    private ShopUser user;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public ShopUser getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public String getResult() {
        return result;
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your ServerResponse class must extends Serializable to get JSON via getters